# How can I automatically position a block in Drupal 7 (via a script, Drush, etc.)?

Tags: 7, blocks, drush

I have a bash script that I use to rebuild my dev environment by re-importing my MySQL database and activating/deactivating modules, etc.

Recently, I've realised that I often need the `Switch user` block provided by the Devel module.

So, ideally, in my script, I'd like to automatically enable the module in the left sidebar.

[This question on how to place a block with Drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2036/5147) looked promising but it suggests using Drush Extras, which [according to the README does not work for Drupal 7](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_extras.git/blob/HEAD:/README.txt).

How can I automatically set the position of the `Switch user` block from the command line?

Comment: Why not by directly querying DB? Drush can do that, so simply updating one table to assign block to region should be doable.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer:**

I just committed https://drupal.org/comment/7000524 to support the Drush block commands in Drupal 7.  I also added a shortcut mode, where arguments can be used in place of options in instances where doing so would be unambiguous.  When calling block-configure from a bash script, though, you should always use the options form; otherwise, your script would break if a specification became ambiguous (e.g. if someone added a block whose delta was named the same as some region).

So, from the commandline:

```
$ drush block-configure switch_user sidebar_second 10
```

From a bash script:

```
drush block-configure --module=devel --delta=switch_user --region=sidebar_second --weight=10
```

The later works just fine from the command line, of course; it's just more typing.